# I have installed "black" in virtual environment using pip, but when I run python -m black my_module.py , it says No module named black

Tags: python, formatter

I have installed **black** Python code formatter using 'pip install black' in my virtual environment. But when I run '''python -m black output.py --check''', output is like this       '''    /usr/bin/python: No module named black.  '''. How to correct this error?

I'm getting same error outside virtual environment as well.

Comment: What OS and version do you have? Is there a possibility that you accidentally installed black to a virtual environment? What does `black output.py` output?
Do you have both Python2 and Python3 installed, have you made sure that you installed black to the correct python version?

Comment: I'm using MacOS. I'm not sure about what difference does it make when you pip install something in virtual environment or outside virtual environment.  '''black output.py''' is doing what I intended to. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned, you installed `black` to a virtual env.
But your output says `/usr/bin/python` which probably means that the virtual environment is not activated.

Try activating it with `source {YOUR_VENV_ROOT}/bin/activate`, if you are using `python-virtualenv`, or activate it by other means, and try again.

You can also access your venv by executing your local python executable: `{YOUR_VENV_ROOT/bin/python -m black output.py --check`